# multiple rows in singleton select

Tags: c#

При выводе таблицы выходит данная ошибка в отладке, что могло вызвать

Описание: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода.

Сведения об исключении: FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException: multiple rows in singleton select

Ошибка источника:

```
        lstOutTable = (crClass.getCatRegl_OutTable()); // строка 533
        if (lstOutTable.Count > 0)  // строка 534
        {  // строка 535
```

> Исходный файл: c:\inetpub\YaKITv4.1.MSH\WEBFORMS\cat_regl.ascx.cs
> Строка: 533

Трассировка стека:

> [IscException: multiple rows in singleton select]
> FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ProcessResponse(IResponse
> response) +70
> FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadResponse()
> +60    FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version12.GdsStatement.Execute() +240
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
> behavior, Boolean returnsSet) +293
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +44
>
> [FbException (0x1400014c): multiple rows in singleton select]
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +185
> YaKIT.C1.DataBase.FireBird.execSqlQuery(String query) +330
> YaKIT.C1.DataBase.DBConnectNotParams.execSqlQuery(String query) +213
>
> [Exception: YaKIT.C1.Database => execSqlQuery :: update z_B24D1A8FAC
> set g1=(select t1.zn101  from data_9002 t1 where t1.gr=3 and t1.ULUS
> is not null and z_B24D1A8FAC.ULUS=t1.ULUS and t1.OKPD is not null and
> z_B24D1A8FAC.OKPD=t1.OKPD  and (t1.razrez in('ОТЧЕТ', 'УЛУС',
> 'ТЕРР')))]    YaKIT.C1.DataBase.DBConnectNotParams.catchThrow(String
> message, Exception ex) +144

```
sql = 'insert into data_9002 (razrez, ulus, okpo, okpd, gr, god, mes, zn0, zn101) select ''РћРўР§Р•Рў'' as razrez, k.ulus, k.okpo, d.s1 as okpd, d.gr as gr, ' || :god || ', ' || :mes || ', 1 as zn0, zn as zn101 from frm_data' || :god || '_period' || :mesv || '_3 d, s_okpo' || :god || '_period' || :mesv || ' k, s_ko' || :god || '_period' || :mesv || '_3 ko where d.ko=k.okpo and d.ko=ko.ko and coalesce(d.zn,0)<>0 and d.st=''10.3.1'''; EXECUTE STATEMENT (:sql) WITH autonomous transaction;

sql = 'insert into data_9002 (razrez, ulus, okpo, okpd, gr, god, mes, zn0, zn101) select ''РћРўР§Р•Рў'' as razrez, k.ulus, k.okpo, ''0'' as okpd, d.gr as gr, ' || :god || ', ' || :mes || ', 1 as zn0, zn as zn101 from frm_data' || :god || '_period' || :mesv || '_3 d, s_okpo' || :god || '_period' || :mesv || ' k, s_ko' || :god || '_period' || :mesv || '_3 ko where d.ko=k.okpo and d.ko=ko.ko and coalesce(d.zn,0)<>0 and d.st=''10.3'''; EXECUTE STATEMENT (:sql) WITH autonomous transaction;
```

> YaKIT.C1.DataBase.DBConnectNotParams.execSqlQuery(String query) +445
> YaKIT.WebForms.csCatRegl.getCatRegl_OutTable() +18277
> YaKIT.WebForms.cat_regl.drawOutTable() in
> c:\inetpub\YaKITv4.1.MSH\WEBFORMS\cat_regl.ascx.cs:533
> YaKIT.WebForms.cat_regl.create() in
> c:\inetpub\YaKITv4.1.MSH\WEBFORMS\cat_regl.ascx.cs:296
> YaKIT.WebForms.cat_regl.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
> c:\inetpub\YaKITv4.1.MSH\WEBFORMS\cat_regl.ascx.cs:143
> System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +108
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +90
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +1607

Comment: Нужно исправлять sql-запрос (который вы не показали). [Multiple rows in singleton select](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq171/)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov пробовал lstOutTable in (crClass.getCatRegl_OutTable()); не хочет работать, добавляя те или иные именя типа "in" "exists" "from" не воспринимает их и добавляю как переменные? редактирую ascx на visual studio 2015

Comment: Проблема в sql-запросе. В трассировке его видно, он начинается с `update z_B24D1A8FAC` и заканчивается `in('ОТЧЕТ', 'УЛУС', 'ТЕРР')))`. Вероятно, подзапрос `select` возвращает не одно значение, а несколько.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov т.е. значение повторяющееся в запросе?

Comment: Select возвращает несколько значений.

Comment: Не пишите код в комментариях. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него всю необходимую информацию.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нашел еще YaKIT.C1.Database.pdb но открыл на visual studio не нашел запрос

Comment: И где вообще их найти эти запросы, чет найти не могу